# How to pass large string_replacement in SQL Replace function

Tags: sql, sql-server, replace

I am attempting to replace a very large characters with a existing character in SQL, like the below

```
select REPLACE('main context', 'text', 'CharactersOver8000')
```

It would throw the following error

```
String or binary data would be truncated.
```

I try to cast the whole replace to nvarchar(max) but it does not work. Any suggestion? Currently its on SQL2012

Comment: Hmmm.  Have you tried to cast before the `replace()`.

Comment: From the **[Docs Online](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)** _If string_expression is not of type varchar(max) or nvarchar(max), REPLACE truncates the return value at 8,000 bytes. To return values greater than 8,000 bytes, string_expression must be explicitly cast to a large-value data type._

Comment: I believe you are referring to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

It says string_expression, but here I'm referring to string_replacement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the cause of this error message?

---

From the **[Docs Online](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)**

> If string_expression is not of type varchar(max) or nvarchar(max), REPLACE truncates the return value at 8,000 bytes. To return values greater than 8,000 bytes, string_expression must be explicitly cast to a large-value data type.

---

What is the solution?

---

`string_expression` in your case is `'MainContext'`, so you need to cast it to `VARCHAR(MAX)` or `NVARCHAR(MAX)` datatypes as

```
select REPLACE(CAST('main context' AS VARCHAR(MAX), 'text', 'CharactersOver8000')
```

Answer (score 0):

Casting inside the replace should work.   I just tested this:

```
SELECT REPLACE(CAST('MainContext' AS varchar(max)), 'text', '{8005 character string}')
```

And it worked.