# How to pass large search character in SQL Replace function

Tags: sql, sql-server, replace

This question is kind of derived from another post [How to pass large string_replacement in SQL Replace function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52899028/how-to-pass-large-string-replacement-in-sql-replace-function/52899153#52899153), but this case the large character is in search portion.

For example,

```
select REPLACE(CAST('CharactersOver10000' AS VARCHAR(MAX), 'CharactersOver8000', 'text' )
```

The above select statement would throw the error

```
String or binary data would be truncated.
```

I learnt that from [Replace documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and suspected the bold part could be the issue, but not really sure what that mean and how to deal with the string_pattern that is more than 8000 characters.

> string_pattern
>   Is the substring to be found. string_pattern can be of a character or binary data type. string_pattern cannot be an empty string (''), and **must not exceed the maximum number of bytes that fits on a page.**

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is second string also need the cast

```
select REPLACE(
               CAST('CharactersOver10000' AS VARCHAR(MAX)),
               CAST('CharactersOver8000' AS VARCHAR(MAX)), 
              'text' )
```

Anyway I did a test using variables and didnt get any error:

**[SQL DEMO](https://rextester.com/UKOX76697)**

```
DECLARE @source VARCHAR(MAX) = '1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890';                                ;
DECLARE @target VARCHAR(MAX);
SET @target = @source + @source + @source + @source + @source + @source + @source + @source + @source + @source;
SET @target = @target + @target + @target + @target + @target + @target + @target + @target;

SET @source = @source + @source + @source + @source + @source + @source + @source + @source + @source + @source;
SET @source = @source + @source + @source + @source + @source + @source + @source + @source + @source + @source;


SELECT len(@source) as source_size,
       len(@target) as target_size       
       ;
```

[image]

```
select REPLACE(CAST(@source as VARCHAR(MAX)), @target, 'text' );      

select REPLACE(@source, @target, 'text' );
```

Comment: add one more + '1' at the second @target and it would blow, it can fit 8000 but not 8001.

Comment: Ok looks like you are screw. But at least now you have a way to reproduce the error. Maybe someone have a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

I think we discussed this **[earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52899028/6426692)**, now according to the **[Docs Online](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/char-and-varchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)**

> varchar [ ( n | max ) ] Variable-length string data. n defines the string length and can be a value from 1 through 8,000. max indicates that the maximum storage size is 2^31-1 bytes (2 GB).

```
REPLACE ( string_expression , string_pattern , string_replacement )
```

So, if you have a string data holds `>8000` you should declare/cast it as `VARCHAR(MAX)/NVARCHAR(MAX)` this applies for the `string_expression` which I answer it in the other question, now looking to your code

```
SELECT REPLACE(
                CAST('CharactersOver10000' AS VARCHAR(MAX),
                'CharactersOver8000', --Here is your problem
                'text' 
              );
```

`string_pattern` must be < `string_expression` and it must be `<= 8000` (*must not exceed the maximum number of bytes that fits on a page.* as stated), if it's `> 8000` the `REPLACE()` function will fail and you get

> String or binary data would be truncated.

---

Solution:

You may consider to split your `string_pattern` into 2 or more parts.

Here is a **[Demo](https://rextester.com/YBSBB9132)** which simulate your case.